PHPWord header: table smaller than on page
Using PHPWord, I want to put a table on the page and one with the same width in the header. However, the table in the header is a little smaller than the one in the body.
This is my code:
$sectionStyle = array(
  'marginTop' => 850,
  'marginLeft' => 850,
  'marginRight' => 850,
  'marginBottom' => 850,
  'orientation' => 'landscape',
);
$section = $phpWord->addSection($sectionStyle);

$table_style = array(
  'unit' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\TblWidth::TWIP,
  'width' => 15138,
  'borderColor' => '000000',
  'borderSize' => 1,
  'cellMargin' => 115,
);
$header = $section->addHeader();
$table_header = $header->addTable($table_style);

$table_body = $section->addTable($table_style);

How to get the tables the same width? Thanks in advance!
